# Parse Swift syntax to Android

Tags: java, android, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I had trouble trying to retrieve user based on search distance, and have received great support from this community. The code boiled down to the following:

```
let userLocation = PFGeoPoint(latitude: userLatitude, longitude: userLongitude)
query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint:userLocation, withinKilometers: 100)
```

The issue is that the code is tailored to swift/xcode, and when I tried "converting it to" android it came down to

```
query.whereWithinKilometers("location", ParseGeoPoint point, 100);
```

I am not sure if this is the proper way of writing it in Java (android), and not sure what to do ParseGeoPoint point.

I have looked into https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseGeoPoint.html, but is a bit stuck.

If you need any clarification, let me know.
Thanks

Update:
Below is how I store the location point of the current user into Parse

```
@Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            double lati = loc.getLatitude();
            double longi = loc.getLongitude();

            ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
            currentUser.saveInBackground();

            ParseGeoPoint point = new ParseGeoPoint(lati, longi);
            currentUser.put("location", point);

            currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                    if (e == null) {
                        // Success!

                    } else {

                    }
                }
            });
```

Below is how I attempt to retrieve it, and see if user who fall within range

```
  ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

        ParseGeoPoint point = new ParseGeoPoint(47, -122); //Ideally it would be best if (47, -122) reflected the current user location
        query.whereWithinKilometers("location", point, 100);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend reading through [this](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#geo) for documentation on the Android SDK's GeoPoints. This would be the basic syntax for you.

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        double lati = loc.getLatitude();
        double longi = loc.getLongitude();

        //User's current location
        ParseGeoPoint point = new ParseGeoPoint(lati, longi);
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Locations");
        query.whereWithinKilometers("location", point, 100);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() { ... });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt responses. I agree I need to dive more into the documentation. for the new ParseGeoPoint(40.0, -30.0), to get the current user 40, and -30, what I did was use the GPS and then put the latitude and longtitude information into parse, and to later retrieve it, but I realize that this is inefficient, but even with tutorials I am unfamiliar with how to grab latitude and longitude using Parse.

Comment: How did you grab the location and store it in Parse?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response and patience. I admittedly admit that I am a novice at this, and is trying my best to learn. I have updated my initial code displaying how I grab location, and attempted to store it into parse.